# Laravel, mostrar a un usuario dependiendo de la fecha (L-V)?

Tags: php, laravel, date

Quiero hacer  en laravel que muestre a un Usuario dependiendo del día del calendario.

Supongamos que tengo una BD con N usuarios, y deben de cubrir un día de guardia en el trabajo de L-V en orden del 1-N,  ej:

-Jueves 2 Agosto: "Le toca hacer guardia al Usuario con ID 1"

-Viernes 3 Agosto: " "" con ID 2"

-Lunes 6 Agosto: " "" con ID 3"

Martes 7 Agosto: " "" con ID 4"

...Hasta llegar al usuario N, y que se repita el ciclo. 1, 2, 3. Dependiendo del día, solo L-V.

Con esta funcion determino los días de la semana excluyendo S-D

```
public function getDiasHabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin, $diasferiados = array())
{
    // Convirtiendo en timestamp las fechas
    $fechainicio = strtotime($fechainicio);
    $fechafin = strtotime($fechafin);

    // Incremento en 1 dia
    $diainc = 24 * 60 * 60;

    // Arreglo de dias habiles, inicianlizacion
    $diashabiles = array();

    // Se recorre desde la fecha de inicio a la fecha fin, incrementando en 1 dia
    for ($midia = $fechainicio; $midia <= $fechafin; $midia += $diainc) {
        // Si el dia indicado, no es sabado o domingo es habil
        if (!in_array(date('N', $midia), array(6, 7))) { // DOC: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php
            // Si no es un dia feriado entonces es habil
            if (!in_array(date('Y-m-d', $midia), $diasferiados)) {
                array_push($diashabiles, date('Y-m-d', $midia));
            }
        }
    }

    return $diashabiles;
}
```

***En la parte de mi controlador en la función edit es lo que tengo para poder agregar los dias de la semana en mi base de datos***

```
public function edit(User $user)

{

    $dias = $this->getDiasHabiles('2018-07-30', '2018-08-06', ['2013-12-16']);
    $usuarios = User::select('id')->get()->toArray();



    for ($j = 0; $j < count($dias); $j++) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($usuarios); $i++) {
          DiaAsignado::create([
               'tddia' => $dias[$j],
                'tdusuario' => '1'
           ]);
       }
    }
    return view('users.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

Nota: Le coloqué un valor por defecto "1" como usuario. 
Lo que realiza es crear en mi tabla 1 las fechas, pero por cada usuario que tengo en mi tabla 2 le asigna la misma fecha, por lo cual crea 5 veces la misma fecha por cada usuario.
El siguiente problema es que quiero colocar el ID de mi tabla 2, en este caso tengo 5 usuarios, y quiero hacer que cuando agregue la fecha también agregue el ID de mi otra tabla.

este es mi modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DiaAsignado extends Model
{
protected $table = "TDASIGN";
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'tddia', 'tdusuario'
];

}
```

La tabla 1 contiene los campos id, tddia y tdusuario. De mi tabla 2 solo ocupo el ID.
Este es el resultado cuando se realiza esa función:

[image: Resultado de la BD]

Como se dan cuenta, duplica las fechas, y lo que yo quiero es que por cada fecha asigne un usuario, o por cada usuario asigne una fecha.

Comment: Para poder intentar ayudarte sería útil saber más sobre cómo te gustaría trabajar con esta información.
Por ejemplo, te gustaría almacenar esto en alguna parte?  Es decir, almacenar inmediatamente en alguna tabla calendario a quién le toca cada día?
O tal vez no quieres guardarlo sino que dinámicamente calcularlo si se hace la consulta por un día o empleado?
Si es así, por alguno hay que partir, el primer sería al azar? por orden de id?
No se si me entiendes pero sería bueno saber de forma más precisa lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Edité un poco la pregunta, quiero que con un ciclo cada que se realice el mismo se cree en mi segunda base de datos la fecha y en seguida el ID del usuario que se le asignará, esto como llave foranea el ID del usuario de la primer tabla y el campo de la segunda tabla, espero explicarme.

Comment: El ultimo ciclo te funciona bien??? te muestra solo las fechas entre el Lunes y el Viernes???

Comment: Hola @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas edité la pregunta para poder explicarme de mejor manera, la función de días habiles funciona de manera correcta, lo que no me funciona es cuando trato de pasarlo a mi base de datos. Gracias

Comment: Hola @JulioLago edité la pregunta para poder explicarme de mejor manera, quiero que se muestre en un calendario el usuario que se asignará al día requerido.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto en el lugar del doble ciclo

```
$user_count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($dias);$i++)
{
   if($user_count < count($usuarios))
   {
     DiaAsignado::create(['tddia'=>$dias[$i],'tdusuario'=>$usuarios[$user_count]]);
     $user_count ++;
   }
   else
   {
     $user_count = 0;
   }
}
```

Estoy asumiendo que obtienes todos los usuarios.
PD. Pon el código en lugar de las imágenes, probablemente tenga errores XD.

Comment: Que tal Christian . Ya realicé la modificación que me comentaste pero me aparece un nuevo error,  "Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `TDASIGN` (`tddia`, `tdusuario`) values (2018-07-30, 3))" y ya cambié las imagenes por el código.

Comment: Probablemente se deba a usuarios, cambia `'tdusuario'=>$usuarios[$user_count]` a `'tdusuario'=>$usuarios[$user_count]->id`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Christian, pero de igual manera no me funciona, me dice que no es un objeto.

Comment: Cambia `'tdusuario'=>$usuarios[$user_count]` a `'tdusuario'=>$usuarios[$user_count]['id']`